# Is it possible to get user input(s) when running a Job in RStudio?

Tags: r

I have a number of long-running scripts to execute, which pull data in from a number of different backend servers, and I want to know if it is possible to run them as Jobs within RStudio and to receive prompts from those scripts where further information required.

Namely, providing passwords to allow the scripts to access to the servers.

The reason I want to run the scripts via Jobs in RStudio is so that I still have access to R in the interim; otherwise, if I run the scripts directly from within RStudio, it will tie up RStudio/R until complete, which can take several hours.

As such, is it possible to have an R Jobs process request user input?

Otherwise, the scripts will simply hang and never complete.

Comment: What is your OS ? Personnally I use the cronR package on a Rstudio Server.

Comment: I am using Windows 10.